# How to replace ClutterTexture with key action?

Tags: c, gtk, gobject, clutter

I want to change the background texture of a Gobject clutter actor whenever it is highlighted. Is there any way i can replace the texture during runtime ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use the `clutter_texture_set_*` family of functions, like:

`clutter_texture_set_from_file`
  `clutter_texture_set_from_rgb_data`
  `clutter_texture_set_area_from_rgb_data`

all documented here: http://developer.gnome.org/clutter/stable/ClutterTexture.html